# Maybe Vocative Comma? Maybe Vocative Phrase?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> **Obedient daily dress,**
>
> You cannot always keep
>
> That untamable young surface.

Do you  call this a vocative comma? — and a vocative phrase? Is it like: “*John*, will you run?”

Comment: Yes, given the context with "you", "obedient daily dress" (skin) is being addressed.   But isn't it "unfakable"?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends entirely on whether "**obedient daily dress**" is what is being addressed. Who or what is 'you'?  If it's the daily dress, then you have a vocative. If not, you have an unusual word order.